# rails app not able to deploy to production due to Stripe secret key being nil in Rails.application.credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, credentials

I have an existing Rails application in which I am trying to implement Stripe checkout.

I have edited `config/credentials.yml.enc` to include my Stripe api keys:

```
# aws:
#   access_key_id: ***
#   secret_access_key: ***

# Used as the base secret for all MessageVerifiers in Rails, including the one protecting cookies. secret_key_base: c8232...

stripe:   
  secret: sk_live_51O...
  public: pk_live_51O...
```

Then I updated `config/initializers/stripe.rb` to store the API key:

```
Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:secret]
```

This works in the development environment. But when I attempt to deploy it to production this is the error message I get:

```
 => ERROR [build 6/6] RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile                                                                                                     1.0s
------
 > [build 6/6] RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile:
#0 0.976 bin/rails aborted!
#0 0.976 NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
#0 0.976 
#0 0.976 Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][:secret]
#0 0.976                                                        ^^^^^^^^^
#0 0.976 /rails/config/initializers/stripe.rb:1:in `<main>'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:683:in `load'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:683:in `block in load_config_initializer'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:682:in `load_config_initializer'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:636:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:635:in `each'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:635:in `block in <class:Engine>'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:423:in `initialize!'
#0 0.976 /rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.17.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:399:in `require_environment!'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:585:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `invoke_prerequisites'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:218:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:182:in `invoke_task'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:138:in `each'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:138:in `block in top_level'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:147:in `run_with_threads'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:132:in `top_level'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:208:in `standard_exception_handling'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:27:in `block in perform'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:44:in `block in with_rake'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:59:in `with_application'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:41:in `with_rake'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:156:in `invoke_rake'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:73:in `block in invoke'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:149:in `with_argv'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:69:in `invoke'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
#0 0.976 /rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.17.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
#0 0.976 Tasks: TOP => environment
#0 0.976 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
------
Error: failed to fetch an image or build from source: error building: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile]: exit code: 1
```

I'm trying to deploy to fly.io and have had no issues with deployment until now. It appears that the RAILS_MASTER_KEY is in fact stored on the machine running the server.

I have followed all the fly.io documentation regarding secret keys I just think there must be something I'm missing.

Comment: Your encrypted file key name doesn't match what you have in your initializer. Switch to `Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:secret]`

Comment: That was a typo. The code that causes the error is what you suggested. The part of the error message that says NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) makes me think that the credentials file is not being decoded properly when deployed because there it says there is nothing there.

Comment: Try dig here: `Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, :secret)`. It has the added benefit of a no method error.

Comment: Generally you should have a credentials file and a key in the same directory with the same name (ie. production.key and production.yml.enc). Do NOT check the key into git.